# What does the "BA/" stands for in this ATIS?

Tags: atis

> LTBA ARR
>   ATIS V
>   0920Z EXP ILS DME APPCH 05 **BA/** FOR RWY 05 TRL 110 AFTER VACATING RWY CONTACT 121.8 WIND RWY 05 340 DEG 07KT VRB BTN 310 AND 020 DEG VIS 9999 FEW/02000 FT BKN/03000 FT T 21 OP 15 QNH 1017 NOSIG
>   END OF ATIS V

Comment: Bracking Action information not available?

Comment: I guess so, may be it was just human mistake.

Comment: That's what my guess is too. Another (educated) guess: Type: A321, Reg: TC-JRP, ADEP: LTCC, ADES: LTBA, ACID: THY3FN. Correct? :-)

Comment: "Sherlock" is that you ? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the **BA/** references "Braking Action" in the ICAO D-ATIS sequence. Since the example report from LBTA (Istanbul Ataturk International Airport) does not suggest that a Braking Action value would be assigned (no rain, etc), it appears to be a *placeholder* for that information if it was provided.

Below is an excerpt from *Annex 11*, to the publication - *Convention on International Civil Aviation (Air Traffic Services)*, showing the sequencing (where it would normally appear in the D-ATIS report) of a Braking Action report (if provided/available).

[image]

Comment: Correct answer. Here is the complete list of ICAO abbreviations. http://www.aopa.org.il/userfiles/files/Technical/ICAO%20abbreviations.pdf

Comment: @JuanJimenez - Good information, thanks